# How to find the minimum of $f(\mathbf{x}) = \| \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b} \|^2_\mathbf{p} + \| \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c} \|^2_\mathbf{q}$

Tags: optimization, least-squares

Let $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$, $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $\mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^{M}$, $\mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$, $\mathbf{p} \in {\mathbb{R}^+}^{M}$ and $\mathbf{q} \in {\mathbb{R}^+}^{N}$. Given fixed $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{b}$, $\mathbf{c}$, $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$, how to solve the following least-squares optimization problem? Does it have a closed-form solution?
$$
\mathbf{x}^* = \arg\min_{\mathbf{x}} \| \mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{b} \|^2_\mathbf{p} + \| \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c} \|^2_\mathbf{q},
$$
where $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2_\boldsymbol{\tau} \triangleq \sum_j (x_j^2 / \tau_j)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Are $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ positive vectors?

Comment: @paulinho yes, all the elements of $\mathbf{p}$ and $\mathbf{q}$ are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to MSE! Usually we encourage the OP to post whatever he/she/they have tried to solve the problem, so try to keep that in mind as you continue your (hopefully long-lasting and meaningful) journey on MSE.

Anyway, to your question. Note that $\|\mathbf{x}\|_\mathbf{\tau} = \|D_\tau \mathbf{x}\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes the standard Euclidean norm in the appropriate dimension and $D_{\tau} = \text{diag}\left(\tau_1^{-1/2}, \tau_2^{-1/2}, \cdots, \tau_n^{-1/2}\right)$. So it suffices to find
$$\mathbf{x}^* = \arg \min_{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \left[\|A \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{b}\|^2 + \|D\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{c}\|^2 \right] ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ (*)$$
for arbitrary constants $A$, $D$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{c}$. (To solve your problem, just take $A$ in $(*)$ to be $D_{\mathbf{p}} A$, $\mathbf{b}$ in $(*)$ to be $D_{\mathbf{p}} \mathbf{b}$, take $D$ in $(*)$ to be $D_\mathbf{q}$, and take $\mathbf{c}$ in $(*)$ to be $D_{\mathbf{q}} \mathbf{c}$.) We can rewrite the objective function as
$$\mathbf{x}^T A^T A \mathbf{x} - 2 \mathbf{b}^T A \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{x}^T D^T D \mathbf{x} - 2 \mathbf{c}^T D \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{c} \\ = \mathbf{x}^T (A^T A + D^T D) \mathbf{x} - 2 (\mathbf{b}^T A + c^T D)\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}^T \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{c}$$
Since the last two terms are constants, the problem is equivalent to minimizing
$$\mathbf{x}^T (A^T A + D^T D) \mathbf{x} - 2(\mathbf{b}^T A + \mathbf{c}^TD) \mathbf{x}$$
Note that $A^T A + D^T D$ is a real symmetric positive definite matrix and can hence be orthogonally diagonalized (see [Spectral Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices)), say as $Q^T E Q$, with $Q$ an orthogonal matrix and $E$ a positive real diagonal matrix. We can then make a change of variables $\mathbf{y} \equiv Q \mathbf{x}$ to get the new objective function
$$\mathbf{y}^T E \mathbf{y} - 2 \mathbf{d}^T \mathbf{y} = (\mathbf{y}^T - 2\mathbf{d}^T E^{-1}) E \mathbf{y}$$
where $\mathbf{d}^T = (b^T A + c^T D) Q^{-1} = (b^T A + c^T D) Q^T$. Since the change of variables from $\mathbf{x}$ to $\mathbf{y}$ was a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, to solve the original problem we can simply find $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ maximizing this modified objective function. But doing so is easy, because if
$$\mathbf{y} = \begin{bmatrix} y_1 & \cdots & y_n \end{bmatrix}^T, ~~ 2 \mathbf{d}^T E^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} f_1 & \cdots & f_n \end{bmatrix}, ~~ E = \text{diag}(e_1, \cdots, e_n)$$
then the objective function is simply
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n e_i (y_i^2 - y_i f_i)$$
whose minimum (recall all the $e_i$ are positive) occurs whenever each $y_i = f_i / 2$ (we just minimize each individual quadratic term). To recover the answer to $(*)$, we simply remember that $\mathbf{x} = Q^{-1} \mathbf{y} = Q^{T} \mathbf{y}$ to obtain the final answer of
$$\mathbf{x} = Q^T (\mathbf{d}^T E^{-1})^{T} = Q^T [E^{-1} Q (A^T \mathbf{b} + D^T \mathbf{c})] = Q^T E^{-1} Q (A^T \mathbf{b} + D^T \mathbf{c}) \\
= (A^T A + D^T D)^{-1} (A^T \mathbf{b} + D^T \mathbf{c})$$
You can check that this agrees with the one variable least-squares solution by taking $D = 0$ and $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$. $\square$

Hence, the answer to the original question is
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}^* &= \left[(D_\mathbf{p} A)^T D_\mathbf{p} A + D_\mathbf{q}^T D_\mathbf{q} \right]^{-1} \left[ (D_\mathbf{p} A)^T D_\mathbf{p} \mathbf{b} + D_\mathbf{q} D_\mathbf{q} \mathbf{c}\right] \\ &= \boxed{(A^T D_\mathbf{p}^2 A + D_\mathbf{q}^2)^{-1} (A^T D_\mathbf{p}^2 \mathbf{b} + D_\mathbf{q}^2 \mathbf{c})}
\end{align*}

Comment: Awesome! This solution really makes sense!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: I think that $D_{\tau} = \text{diag}(\sqrt {\tau_1}, \sqrt {\tau_2}, \cdots, \sqrt {\tau_n})$ should be $D_{\tau} = \text{diag}(1/\sqrt {\tau_1}, 1/\sqrt {\tau_2}, \cdots, 1/\sqrt {\tau_n})$?

Comment: @Urusai That's correct - I've fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Before we start deriving the solution, some facts and notations for brevity:

- Trace and Frobenius product relation $$\left\langle A, B C\right\rangle={\rm tr}(A^TBC) := A : B C$$
- Cyclic properties of Trace/Frobenius product
  \begin{align}
  A : B C 
   &= BC : A \\
   &= A C^T   :  B  \\
   &= {\text{etc.}} \cr
  \end{align}

For convenience, define two diagonal matrices (assuming $p>0$ and $q>0$)
$$D_p:= \frac{1}{p} I$$
and
$$D_q:= \frac{1}{q} I.$$

Remark: the weighted norm definition is bit unusual in OP's question.

Let
\begin{align}
f 
&= \| Ax - b\|_p^2 + \| x - c\|_q^2 \\
&= \left(Ax - b \right)^T D_p \left(Ax - b \right) + \left(x - c \right)^T D_q \left(x - c \right)\\
&\equiv  \left(Ax-y\right): D_p\left(Ax-y\right) +  \left(x-c\right): D_q\left(x-c\right) 
\end{align}

Now, we can obtain the differential first, and then the gradient.
\begin{align}
df  
&= Adx: D_p\left(Ax-y\right) + \left(Ax-y\right): D_pAdx +  dx: D_q\left(x-c\right) + \left(x-c\right): D_qdx \\
&= 2A^T D_p\left(Ax-y\right):dx  + 2\left(x-c\right):dx
\end{align}

Thus, the gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2A^T D_p\left(Ax-y\right) + 2\left(x-c\right).
\end{align}

Now, set the gradient to zero then obtain solution.
\begin{align}
2A^T D_p\left(Ax-y\right) + 2\left(x-c\right) = 0 \Longrightarrow x = \left(A^TD_pA + I \right)^{-1} \left( A^T D_p y + c \right).
\end{align}

Comment: Good job! I found that  I was failed to solve this problem because I don't know how to deal with the weighted norm.